# How can I compile C code that has already been C pre-processed with GCC?

Tags: c, compilation

I'm performing some source processing between C preprocessing and C compilation. At the moment I:

1. `gcc -E file.c > preprocessed_file.c`.
2. Do more stuff to `preprocessed_file.c`.
3. Continue the compilation with `preprocessed_file.c`.

If you attempt to compile `preprocessed_file.c` as you would if it was normal C (step 3) you get lots of the following:

```
/usr/include/stdio.h:257: error: redefinition of parameter ‘restrict’
/usr/include/stdio.h:257: error: previous definition of ‘restrict’ was here
/usr/include/stdio.h:258: error: conflicting types for ‘restrict’
/usr/include/stdio.h:258: error: previous definition of ‘restrict’ was here
/usr/include/stdio.h:260: error: conflicting types for ‘restrict’
[...]
```

And that's just using `#include <stdio.h>` in `file.c`. Fortunately there's an option to tell GCC it's acting on C code that has already been preprocessed by specifying the language that is being compiled as `c-cpp-output` (see `-x` on [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.4/gcc/Overall-Options.html) page). But it doesn't work. I just get this:

```
$ gcc -x c-cpp-output -std=c99 bar.c
i686-apple-darwin9-gcc-4.0.1: language c-cpp-output not recognized
i686-apple-darwin9-gcc-4.0.1: language c-cpp-output not recognized
ld warning: in bar.c, file is not of required architecture
Undefined symbols:
  "_main", referenced from:
      start in crt1.10.5.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And exactly the same response with a newer version of GCC:

```
$ gcc-mp-4.4 -x c-cpp-output -std=c99 bar.c
[same error stuff comes here]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a typo in the GCC docs - try '-x cpp-output' instead.

```
gcc -E helloworld.c > cppout
gcc -x cpp-output cppout -o hw
./hw
Hello, world!
```

Comment: Well that worked with a hello world but not with my code. Lemme see what's going on.

Comment: Maybe try 'gcc -x cpp-output -std=c99 xyz.cppoutput'?

Comment: is there a similar option in visual studio ?

Answer (score 4):

The warnings about `restrict` are due to the fact that it is a keyword in C99.  So, you have to pre-process and compile your code using the same standard.

The error about `_main` is because your file doesn't define `main()`?  Doing the following should work:

```
gcc -c -std=c99 bar.c
```

and it will create `bar.o`.  If your `bar.c` *has* a `main()` defined in it, maybe it is not called `bar.c`?  For example, I created a `bar.c` with a valid `main()`, and did:

```
gcc -E -std=c99 bar.c >bar.E
gcc -std=c99 bar.E
```

and got:

```
Undefined symbols:
  "_main", referenced from:
      start in crt1.10.6.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

In that case, you need the `-x c` option:

```
gcc -x c -std=c99 bar.E
```

(Or, as Nikolai mentioned, you need to save the pre-processed file to `bar.i`.)

Answer (score 2):

Save the file with the `.i` suffix after pre-processing. Gcc man page:

```
       file.i
           C source code which should not be preprocessed.

       file.ii
           C++ source code which should not be preprocessed.
```

Comment: $ gcc -std=c99 bar.i

In file included from bar.h:4,
                 from bar.cex:4:
/usr/include/stdio.h:327: error: syntax error before ‘--’ token
/usr/include/stdio.h:335: error: syntax error before ‘__stdoutp’
/usr/include/stdio.h:383: error: static declaration of ‘__sputc’ follows non-static declaration
/usr/include/stdio.h:334: error: previous declaration of ‘__sputc’ was here

Comment: @Ollie: How are you pre-processing the files?  What's the command you use for that?