# Output to a text file the pre-compiler code

Tags: c, shell, redirect

gcc 4.4.2 c89

I have a file called main.c.

I want the result of the pre-comiler and save it to a text file.

I have done the following which creates a text file, but there is nothing in it. It is zero bytes.

```
gcc -E main.c | > main.txt
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: A (somewhat) standard extension for pre-processed code is `.i`

Comment: Note: That is the **preprocessed** source code. Precompiled (headers) are in binary form, and the result not of just the preprocessor but also some of the compiler steps being performed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a pipe operator for redirecting output to a text file.  Just use

```
gcc -E main.c > main.txt
```

Comment: Found the answer in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133009/how-can-i-compile-c-code-that-has-already-been-c-pre-processed-with-gcc. However, I did try that and it didn't work for me. I was getting some errors saying that it couldn't find some header files. However ,that is the correct way to do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the obvious error:

```
gcc -E main.c > main.txt
```

... you can also use the C preprocessor directly:

```
cpp main.c > output.c
```

...which has the added benefit of being independed of the compiler and possible to use in another toolchain.

In both cases in case of problems, take a look at preprocessor [command line options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1.1/cpp/Invocation.html).

Answer (score 1):

get rid of the `|`, or use `gcc -E main.c -o main.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into the ‘cpp‘ program, which is the C preprocessor that gcc uses.

```
cpp in.c > out.c
```