# in some cases the linker allows multiple modules to define global symbols with the same name?

Tags: c, gcc, gnu, elf

I'm reading a textbook which says:

***we saw how the compiler assigns symbols to COMMON and .bss using a seemingly arbitrary convention. Actually, this convention is due to the fact that in some cases the linker allows multiple modules to define global symbols with the same name.***

But isn't that you can only define a variable once? in which cases linker allow you to define a variable more than once?

Comment: Linkers can support features that C does not. COMMON sections have existed for a long time with FORTRAN, so linkers support them. That does not mean the C standard fully supports this. The C standard makes some allowance for this by saying it does not define what happens when you define something more than once, including via *tentative definitions*. Individual compilers and linkers may fill in this opportunity left by the C standard to define the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This comes around all the time, so here is an actual build which covers the permutations of this:

```
#- Makefile -----
all: 1 2 3 12 13 23
    -./1
    -./2
    -./3
    -./12
    -./13
    -./23
1: main.o 1.o; $(CC) main.o 1.o -o $@
2: main.o 2.o; $(CC) main.o 2.o -o $@
3: main.o 3.o; $(CC) main.o 3.o -o $@
12: main.o 1.o 2.o; $(CC) main.o 1.o 2.o -o $@
13: main.o 1.o 3.o; $(CC) main.o 1.o 3.o -o $@
23: main.o 2.o 3.o; $(CC) main.o 2.o 3.o -o $@
/* ----  1.c ----- */
int num;
/* ----  2.c ----- */
extern int num;
/* ----  3.c ----- */
int num = 2;
/* ---- main.c --- */
#include <stdio.h>

extern int num;

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", num);
    return 0;
}
```

Ok, and after you have surgically deconstructed this SO-archive, and run:

```
make -i all
You should get an output something like:
cc main.o 2.o -o 2
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_num", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: [2] Error 1 (ignored)
./1
0
./2
make: ./2: No such file or directory
make: [all] Error 1 (ignored)
./3
2
./12
0
./13
2
./23
2
```

So, first up, the program *2* doesn't build.   Why not? Because 2.c contains an explicit declaration of an external variable (num); so when linked with main.c, both have expressed an interest in num; but neither have defined it.

In contrast, both ./1 and ./12 have managed to define it, but have not assigned it a value, thus it is defined as zero.  The lack of *extern* in 1.c provides the impetus for the linker to shrug and say, ok, I will just allocate space for it in the zero section (bss).

./3 ./13 ./23 demonstrate that in the presence of a defining statement (int num = 2;) we see the expected result.

What is left out, but may be a good exercise, is what happens if you:
`$(CC) main.c 1.c 1.c 1.c -o 111`?  Do you get an error?  Why not?

Answer (score -1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774759/in-c-is-it-valid-to-declare-a-variable-multiple-times) might shed some light.
Short version:
You can "tentatively declare" a variable as many times as you'd like. I.E
`int i;`
But you can only "externally declare" it ONCE
`int i = 1;`
You'd have to read up on the documentation or wait for a more detailed answer for more information. This was just what i found on the topic right now.

Comment: `int i;` , this is uninitialized global variable , can  uninitializing  a global variable called a definition of a variable?